# Jackson: Parse xml ignoring line separators

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an xml that holds some text blocks within a list of items. The items hold some formatted text. It is formatted using line brakes and spaces before new lines (standard formatting of my IDE). For example:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <title>Long text Item</title>
        <content>
            Some long long long text that I
            want to format using line brakes 
            so that it will be more readable 
            in source code.
        </content>
    </item>
    ...
<items>
```

I read the XML using the following code:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
List<ItemDTO> result = mapper.readValue(
        inputStream, new TypeReference<List<ItemDTO>>() {}
);
```

**Problem:** Such parsing preserves line brakes and spacing inside `content` element.

**Question:** How can I parse the XML ignoring spacing and line brakes in `content` element?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your pojo like:

```
class ItemDTO {
  private String title;
  private String content;
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
  public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }
  public void setContent(String content) {
    if (content != null) {
      this.content = content.replace("\n", " ");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for some Jackson's out of the box solution

Comment: There is no Jackson's out of the box solution to handle this. Have you tried using a jackson custom deserializer?